# How can I set Zend Studio 10.0.1 to use Spaces for Tabs in PHP files?

Tags: php, eclipse, indentation, zend-studio

I set these options:

General/Editors/Text Editors - Insert spaces for tabs [checked]

PHP/Code Style/Formatter - Edit profile Eclipse[built in], rename profile to Eclipse[my] - Indentation(tab) - Tab policy: [Spaces only]

But it still using tabs for indentation.

Comment: I have the Zend Framework 1 Conventions buit in profile selected and it works.

Comment: Thank you. I found out that Aptana Studio installed recently was conflicting with Zend Studio. Both of them are Eclipse projects so Aptana set some common Eclipse settings which was incompatible with Zend Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Another setting you need to change is for html files:

Window->Preferences->Web->HTML Files->Editor->Indent Using Spaces

So in summary this are the necessary steps:

- Window->Preferences->General->Editors->Text Editors->Insert Spaces for Tabs
- Window->Preferences->Web->HTML Files->Editor->Indent Using Spaces
- Window->Preferences->PHP->Code Style->Formatter and create a new profile

Here is a nice post describing each step, hope it helps:

[Zend Studio - insert spaces for tabs](http://www.phpepe.com/2013/12/zend-studio-insert-spaces-for-tabs.html)

Answer (score 1):

Aptana Studio 3 was the reason for such behavior. Obviously it set some eclipse settings which are conflicted with Zend Studio. Uninstalling Aptana and re-installing Zend Studio solved this issue.